# Generation a subgroup of $GL_2(\mathbb{C})$

Tags: group-theory, linear-groups

Let $G$ be a group and let $S$ be a nonempty subset of a group $G$.
The subgroup of $G$ generated by $S$, which is denoted by $\langle S\rangle$,
is equal to the set of all elements of $G$ that can be written as products $s_1s_2\ldots s_k$, for some integer $k\geq1$, where each $s_i$ is in $S\cup S^{-1}$.
Equivalently, a subgroup generated by $S$ is the intersection of all subgroups which contain $S$.

Clearly, if $S$ consists of one element $S=\{s\}$,
then $\langle S\rangle=\langle s\rangle=\{s^k\mid k\in\mathbb{Z}\}$.
But what about if $|S|>1$.

Is there any rule for computing the subgroup $H$ generated by $S$ when $S$ is a finite set?

For example,
it seems a bit difficult to determine which subgroup of
$GL_2(\mathbb{C})$ is
$$
\left<  \begin{pmatrix} e^{\frac{\pi i}{2^{n-2}}} & 0 \\ 0 & e^{-\frac{\pi i}{2^{n-2}}} \end{pmatrix} ,
  \begin{pmatrix}
   0 & -1 \\1 & 0
   \end{pmatrix},  
\begin{pmatrix}
   0 & 1 \\1 & 0
   \end{pmatrix}\right>.
$$
Is there any algorithm or something else that could help?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are interested in what elements this subgroup is made up of, it looks like it would be something like this:
$$
\left<  \begin{pmatrix} e^{\frac{\pi i}{2^{n-2}}} & 0 \\ 0 & e^{-\frac{\pi i}{2^{n-2}}} \end{pmatrix} ,
  \begin{pmatrix}
   0 & -1 \\1 & 0
   \end{pmatrix},  
\begin{pmatrix}
   0 & 1 \\1 & 0
   \end{pmatrix}\right>
$$
$$=
\left\{
  \begin{pmatrix}
   0 & \pm\alpha^k \\
   \pm\bar\alpha^k & 0
   \end{pmatrix},  
  \begin{pmatrix}
   \pm\alpha^k & 0\\
   0 &\pm\bar\alpha^k
   \end{pmatrix}\mid k\in\mathbb{Z}
\right\},
$$
where $\alpha=e^{\frac{\pi i}{2^{n-2}}}$.

**Supplement.**

Answer to the question: How did I come to this conclusion?

1. It is checked directly that
   $$
   H=\left<\
     \begin{pmatrix}
      0 & -1 \\1 & 0
      \end{pmatrix},  
   \begin{pmatrix}
      0 & 1 \\1 & 0
      \end{pmatrix}\right>=
   \left\{
     \begin{pmatrix}
      0 & \pm1 \\
      \pm1 & 0
      \end{pmatrix},  
     \begin{pmatrix}
      \pm1 & 0\\
      0 &\pm1
      \end{pmatrix}
   \right\}.
   $$
2. Let
   $$
   F=\left<\
     \begin{pmatrix}
      \alpha & 0 \\0 & \bar\alpha
      \end{pmatrix}
   \right>=
   \left\{
     \begin{pmatrix}
      \alpha^k & 0 \\0 & \bar\alpha^k
      \end{pmatrix}\mid k\in\mathbb{Z}
   \right\}.
   $$

3. It remains to note that $FH=HF$. Here it is important that $\alpha^{-1}=\bar\alpha$ or equivalently $|\alpha|=1$.

Comment: How did you come to this conclusion?

Comment: This question seems not to meet the standards for the site. Instead of answering it, it would be better to look for a good duplicate target, or help the user by posting comments suggesting improvements. Please also read the [meta announcement](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/33508/) regarding quality standards.